# Eclipse doesn't start after plugin installation

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

I installed a plugin for JavaScript editor in Eclipse, and after a restart, it doesn't start anymore.

This is the trace

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2014-09-26 11:40:17.156
!MESSAGE Unexpected error loading extension: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.simpleRepository
!STACK 0

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.restoreSpecialRepositories(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeArtifactRepository(RepositoryListener.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initialize(RepositoryListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport cannot be found by org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.1.R36x_v20100901
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    ... 38 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2014-09-26 11:40:17.166
!MESSAGE Unexpected error loading extension: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.artifactRepository
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatesite.artifact.UpdateSiteArtifactRepositoryFactory.loadRepository(UpdateSiteArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatesite.artifact.UpdateSiteArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(UpdateSiteArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.restoreSpecialRepositories(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeArtifactRepository(RepositoryListener.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initialize(RepositoryListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport cannot be found by org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.1.R36x_v20100901
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    ... 40 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2014-09-26 11:40:17.169
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.create(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryCreate(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.doCreateRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.createRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.restoreSpecialRepositories(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeArtifactRepository(RepositoryListener.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initialize(RepositoryListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport cannot be found by org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.1.R36x_v20100901
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    ... 35 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.create(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryCreate(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.doCreateRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.createRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.restoreSpecialRepositories(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeArtifactRepository(RepositoryListener.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initialize(RepositoryListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport cannot be found by org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.1.R36x_v20100901
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    ... 35 more
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, even with a clean start, Eclipse doesn't start anymore. So I trashed my Eclipse and now I use a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that have more than one jre installed, i.e. 32/64 bit jre, cause eclipse to fail start.

I've resolved this issue adding in eclipse.ini the line

`-vm <path_to_jre/jdk>`

just before the line

`--launcher.appendvmargs
vmargs ...`